# In what ways can access token update be triggered for administrator accounts on workstations?

Tags: windows, active-directory, access-control-list, groups, uac

This scenario emerged when changing the domain group membership that bestows membership in `BUILTIN\Administrators`.  In particular, the group membership for the administrator did not update on the workstation until the administrator signed in to the desktop as a normal user would. This is the scenario that raised this question:

> Starting setup:
>
> - Domain group `WSAdminGroup1` with member
>
>   - `admin1`
> - Workstation `ws1`:
>
>   - `WSAdminGroup1` is a member of `BUILTIN\Administrators`
>   - `user1` is a member of `BUILTIN\Users`
> - when `user1` encounters a UAC prompt, `admin1` can authorize the elevation
>
> Changes:
>
> - Add domain group `WSAdminGroup2` with member
>
>   - `admin2`
> - Add `WSAdminGroup2` to `BUILTIN\Administrators`
>
> Result:
>
> - when `user1` encounters a UAC prompt, `admin2` cannot authorize the elevation

So we have an administrator `admin2` who should have membership in `BUILTIN\Administrators` on workstation `ws1` by way of their domain group membership in `WSAdminGroup2` but is unable to authorize UAC elevations prompts on `ws1`.

No amount of waiting, rebooting, or signing out by `user1` caused `admin2` to gain administrator access on the workstation.  It turned out that signing in to the workstation desktop as `admin2` finally caused `admin2` to gain administrator access.

This suggests that administrator `admin2`'s access token was not updated on workstation `ws1` until `admin2` logged in to the desktop.  But I haven't yet found documentation that agrees with that conclusion.

In any case I'd like to get to the bottom of the following questions:

1. What really happened to administrator `admin2`'s access tokens as this scenario played out?
2. For identities (like administrators) who do not regularly sign in to a workstation's desktop, is there any other way to trigger issuance of a new access token that would reflect more up-to-date group membership?
3. Do any of the ways of authorizing that don't involve signing in to the desktop (like PowerShell remoting, or invoking "Run as administrator") cause the issuance of a new access token to occur?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using the [Protected Users capability of Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/credentials-protection-and-management/protected-users-security-group) (as discussed in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1185831)) to prevent caching of admin credentials at all. This helps mitigate lateral movement risks, too.